# Database path on raspberry

Tags: php, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi3

I'm new in raspberry and I'm trying to read a simple database from a php page but there is something wrong: I can't read the database content: Here the php page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<H1>Test Database</H1>

<?php

$sq = sqlite_open('miodatabase.db', 0666, $sqlite_error);

if(!$sq)
{
   die(“Errore Sqlite: “.$sqlite_error);
}

$result = sqlite_query($sq, 'select * from test');
while($data = sqlite_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $data[‘nome’];
}
sqlite_close($sq);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The database is "miodatabase" that contains a table called "test". I put the database in \var\www\html folder (is correct?) but when I open the page I see a blank page. I'm sure the database contains the table (tested with sqlite3 commands) and the table contains one row. Where I need to put the database? Why I can't see nothing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved: I type again the command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and then I can see in the php info the sections about sqlite3.
The I update my php page like this:

```
//Enable show error
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);


$db = new SQLite3("miodatabase.db");

$sql_select='SELECT * FROM test'; 
$result=$db->query($sql_select); 

echo "<table border='1'>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
$numColumns=$result->numColumns(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $numColumns; $i++) 
{ 
    $colname=$result->columnName($i); 
    echo "<th>$colname</th>"; 
} 
echo "</tr>"; 
while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM)) 
{ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numColumns; $i++) 
    { 
        $value=$row[$i]; 
        echo "<th>$value</th>"; 
    } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";
```

To open the database I use now

```
$db = new SQLite3("miodatabase.db");
```

because the sqlite_open is not supported by this version of sqlite.
Now all works correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see anything, i think it's a php configuration issue.

Did you try to add :

```
  <?php  phpinfo(); ?>
```

at the beginning of your script. If you have blank page, look your apache/nginx configuration.

You can also try to run your script from the command line. Maybe helpful in some case.

**UPdate**

If you use SQLite3 follow this code

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('miodatabase.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();
$result = $db->query('select * from test', SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE );

//var_dump($result->fetchArray());
while($data = $result->fetchArray())
{
   echo $data[‘nome’];
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: If I put the php info only, then I see the php info.... I think is a problem related to the database path... where I can put the database and how can I specify the path in the open command?

Comment: Ok. And www-data (or your apache/nginx unix user)  is the owner of 'miodatabase.db' ?

Comment: For simple test put your database in the same path of your script and you don't have to change your code. If not you have to set the complete path of your database in the open function. 
`$sq = sqlite_open('/var/www/html/miodatabase.db', 0666, $sqlite_error);`

Comment: no, the owner of the database is 'pi' as i can see using ls -la command

Comment: now is www-data but nothing to do... blank page... if I comment the php, I can see the page title... there is something wrong in the syntax I think

Comment: Did you show php errors ? Cause i tried to run your code and i see this :  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in /var/www/test.php on line 8` because my version is sqlite3 and sqlite_open is for sqlite2

Comment: I have this error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/page.php on line 26.

Comment: I found a solution but thanks a loto for your support!